# Filter word from filename | bash regex

Tags: regex, bash

I want the name from fielnames like this:

> abc-dirk-alt.avi

and I only want the part between the --  (dirk)
The normal regex is `-(.*?)-`  but i dont know how to write this in a bash script.
how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a `-([^-]*)-` regex (`[^-]*` matches zero or more chars other than `-`) to avoid using lazy quantifiers and extract Group 1 value via `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` after a match is found:

```
s="abc-dirk-alt.avi"
rx="-([^-]*)-"
if [[ $s =~ $rx ]]; then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]};
fi
```

See the [online Bash demo](https://ideone.com/8XuJwW).

Comment: I have this code: https://ideone.com/pCM6Et 
but that dosnt work for me

Comment: @Adrian Do not use a space between the var and `=`, use `re="-([^-]*)-"`